# Is there a way to return std::vector ref from a map of vectors when the requested key is missing?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, stl, stdmap

*Quick note: I don't currently have access to C++11 on this project, so while I'm interested to hear any answers using it, I wouldn't be able to use anything C++11-specific.*

---

I've got a class that manages a collection of objects. This data is stored in a map of vectors, with an enum "object type" as key:

```
std::map<MyEnum, std::vector<MyObject *> > m_objectMap;
```

The enum value is part of the object, so the collection is initially populated like so:

```
void MyCollection::AddObject(MyObject *object)
{
    m_objectMap[object->GetType()].push_back(object);
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do now is have a function that takes an enum value and returns a const reference to the corresponding vector. I can do this as follows:

```
const std::vector<MyObject *> &MyCollection::GetObjectsForType(MyEnum eType)
{
    return m_objectMap[eType];
}
```

The only problem is, using `std::map::operator[]` is non-`const`, since it adds a pair if the requested enum type doesn't exist in the collection, which means this function can't be `const`. Alternatively, if I check the map to see if it contains the key first, I don't know what to return if the key doesn't exist, since it has to be a const reference to *something*.

And so, I'm looking for suggestions on a better way to design this collection (or a way to return an empty const vector reference). The main goals are centred around ease of use:

- ability to add an object by simply passing it in (automatically sorted by type)
- ability to get all objects of a given type
- ability to query the number of objects of a given type (i.e. `vector.size()`)

Thank you!

Comment: You could make `m_objectMap` `mutable`.

Comment: You could return a reference to a special "NA" object to indicate that there is no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
const std::vector<MyObject *> &GetObjectsForType(MyEnum eType)
{
    static const std::vector<MyObject *> empty_vec;
    auto it = m_objectMap.find(eType);
    return it != m_objectMap.end() ? it->second : empty_vec;
}
```

Regarding the overall design, `std::multimap<MyEnum, MyObject *>` would be my choice.  Then `GetObjectsForType()` could be:

```
std::pair<iterator, iterator> GetObjectsForType(MyEnum eType)
{
    return m_objectMap.equal_range(eType);
}
```

I'd also consider using `boost::unique_ptr<MyObject>` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a static empty list, I like that! I haven't used `multimap` before though, looks like it would work well here. Just one correction; in your first code block, I believe the return should be `it->second`, not just `*it`. We do have a more robust shared pointer type, I just used raw pointers to simplify the examples. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerVezina: Glad that helped.  I fixed the `it->second` thing.